# NoMethodError :undefined method `preferred_filename_on_disk_location' for nil:NilClass

Tags: chef-infra

I am newbie in ruby and chef. I was trying to create a file through template resource. After running chef-apply command , I am getting some error "NoMethodError :undefined method `preferred_filename_on_disk_location' for nil:NilClass " . I tried to google it, but no correct solution found.

Please help.

## chef-apply abc.rb

Recipe: (chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe)
  * template[file.txt] action create

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[file.txt]'
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `preferred_filename_on_disk_location' for nil:NilClass

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In abc.rb

 10: template "file.txt" do
 11:     source "file.erb"
 12:     mode "0666"
 13: end
 14: 

Compiled Resource:
```

# Declared in abc.rb:10:in `run_chef_recipe'

```
template("file.txt") do
  action [:create]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  source "file.erb"
  declared_type :template
  cookbook_name "(chef-apply cookbook)"
  recipe_name "(chef-apply recipe)"
  mode "0666"
  path "file.txt"
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

[2017-01-02T18:37:07-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-01-02T18:37:07-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-01-02T18:37:07-05:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: template[file.txt] ((chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe) line 10) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `preferred_filename_on_disk_location' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try and fix the formatting of your question - it will be much easier to help you if your code and error messages are properly formatted.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `chef-apply` is not able to run the template resource properly (see https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5317). As a better approach to run your recipes, you should use `chef-solo`.

The command would be

```
chef-solo -o 'recipe[COOKBOOK_NAME]' -c CONFIG_FILE
```

where `CONFIG_FILE` contains some configuration for Chef, e.g.

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

file_cache_path '/tmp/chef-cache'
cookbook_path ["#{current_dir}/cookbooks"]
data_bag_path "#{current_dir}/databags"
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
```

You can call this file `solo.rb`, put it in the same directory where you run the Chef command above, then it will look like

```
chef-solo -o 'recipe[COOKBOOK_NAME]' -c solo.rb
```

Replace `COOKBOOK_NAME` with the name of the cookbook you want to run, add `::recipe_name` if you want to run the `recipe_name.rb` recipe and not the `default.rb` recipe.

Comment: May worth adding a link to https://learn.chef.io as OP's seems to lack basic knowledge of chef. Moving from a single recipe with chef-apply to a cookbook and chef-zero or solo is not so easy when you only know chef-apply (which is aimed at quick configuration of local host only)

Comment: I fixed this to use chef-solo which is correct for current versions.